# Port change on-the-fly

Tags: port, nginx, iis

I have an API which reads only on ports 80/443 and I have an IIS server app that should talk with this API but the 80/443 ports are taken by Nginx.
Is there a service that takes the API data sent from my server on any other port and it over to the service with 80/443 ports ?
This simple hack can save me hundreds of $ in maintenance of another server.

Comment: Can you shed some light on which system is running IIS, which one nginx and which one the API ?

Answer (score 2):

It's one of the functions of a HTTP ["reverse proxy"](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/). Nginx can be configured to forward certain requests to *another* HTTP(S) server, using the `proxy_pass` setting. (You can choose to proxy an entire vhost, or certain directories, or even just a single URL.)

```
server {
    server_name myapi.example.com;

    listen *:80; listen [::]:80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
        # IIS host:port goes here.
    }
}
```